# ERROR 1005 (HY000) | Can't create table

Tags: mysql

```
create table finishedMaterials(
FinishedMaterialID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FinishedMaterialType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FinishedMaterialWeight INT(5) NOT NULL,
FinishedMaterialUnits INT(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (FinishedMaterialID))ENGINE=INNODB;

create table vehicles(
VehicleID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
VehicleNumber VARCHAR(8),
VehicleType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
VehicleCondition VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
VehicleRemarks VARCHAR(100),
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (VehicleID))ENGINE=INNODB;

create table transport(
TransportID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
VehicleID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FinishedMaterialID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FinishedMaterialUnits INT(5) NOT NULL,
FinishedMaterialWeight INT(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (TransportID),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (VehicleID) REFERENCES vehicles(VehicleID),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FinishedMaterialID) REFERENCES finishedMaterials(FinishedMaterialID),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FinishedMaterialUnits) REFERENCES finishedMaterials(FinishedMaterialUnits),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FinishedMaterialWeight) REFERENCES finishedMaterials(FinishedMaterialWeight))ENGINE=INNODB;
```

---

• What's wrong in this code? What's causing this error? Please help. All the other tables, including the top 2 of this code works perfectly, except for the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last 2 foreign keys do not reference indexed keys in the primary table

Edit:  And they shouldn't. FinishedMaterialWeight and FinsihedMaterialUnits are not unique keys to the finishedMaterials table.  Only FinishedMaterialID is needed.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia..

*"A foreign key is a field in a relational table that matches a **candidate key of another table.** The foreign key can be used to cross-reference tables."*

Whereas,

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FinishedMaterialUnits) REFERENCES finishedMaterials(FinishedMaterialUnits),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (FinishedMaterialWeight) REFERENCES finishedMaterials(FinishedMaterialWeight))ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Above columns, FinishedMaterialUnits and FinishedMaterialWeight, are not candidate keys in their tables.

I think your design is a bit flawed since these two columns are not SUPPOSED to be unique for every row in a table. For example, the unit count can repeat.